# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in VideosController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am getting the following error in rubymine and rails, and I am completely new to the environments, and I dont know how to fix it:

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in VideosController#create

I am using Rails 3.2.15 & ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

I am "trying" to build a web application using the aforementioned tech. It is to do with a basic video rental store. In which I have (presently) 4 tables. Users, Videos, Rentals, Genres. I will later add a cart and login using devise, along with a basic custom gem which may require additional tables.

I get this error when I try to enter a new video or rental. I have no problems entering genre or users. So I assume its to do with the relationships because when I remove them it works.

I used the following scaffolding commands inside of rubymine to create my 4 tables.

```
user first_name:string{25} last_name:string{25} user_name:string{25} password:string{25} address:string email:string{150} phone:string{15} dob:date verified:boolean admin:boolean

#I added the following to the resulting user.rb model file
has_many :rentals

#Below is the code generated (and slightly modified) for the user.rb model file
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rentals
    attr_accessible :address, :admin, :dob, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :phone, :user_name, :verified
end


genre genre_title:string{50}

#I added the following to the resulting genre.rb model file
has_many :videos

#Below is the code generated (and slightly modified) for the genre.rb model file
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :videos
    attr_accessible :genre_title
end



video title:string{50} genre_title:string{50} description:text purchase_price:decimal rental_price:decimal sale_price:decimal image_url:string genre:references

#I added the following to the resulting video.rb model file
has_many :rentals
belongs_to :genre

#Below is the code generated (and slightly modified) for the video.rb model file
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rentals
    belongs_to :genre
    attr_accessible :description, :genre_title, :image_url, :purchase_price, :rental_price, :sale_price, :title
end



rental user:references video:references borrowed_date:datetime returned_date:datetime due_date:datetime

#I added the following to the resulting rental.rb model file
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :video

#Below is the code generated (and slightly modified) for the rental.rb model file
class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
  attr_accessible :borrowed_date, :due_date, :returned_date
end
```

This did generate the appropriate attr_accessible lines which I modified slightly because a few fields were left out and I thought that would fix the problem.

This supposedly sets up the tables and the relationships. as I want. I say supposedly because when I go into SQLite3 and enter data that breaks the relational integrity (i.e. a rental with invalid user or video id's). It allows it. So the error is not coming back from the DB (even though it should be).

I normally use C# and Entity frameworks on top of SQL Server...Instead I am trying to learn ruby on rails with active record and SQLite3. Its a slow and painful process so far but I really want to give the platform a good chance as I have heard lots of good stuff about it.

Below is further code I have been asked to add. I hope it helps and thank you.

```
  #This is the create action from the video controller
  # POST /videos
  # POST /videos.json
  def create
    @video = Video.new(params[:video])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @video.save
        format.html { redirect_to @video, notice: 'Video was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @video, status: :created, location: @video }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @video.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end



<!-- This is the _form.html.erb video view -->
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre_title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :genre_title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :purchase_price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :purchase_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :rental_price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :rental_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sale_price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :sale_price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :genre %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :genre %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>



<!-- This is the new.html.erb video view -->
<h1>New video</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', videos_path %>



<!-- This is the index.html.erb video view -->
<h1>Listing videos</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Genre title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Purchase price</th>
    <th>Rental price</th>
    <th>Sale price</th>
    <th>Image url</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @videos.each do |video| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= video.title %></td>
    <td><%= video.genre_title %></td>
    <td><%= video.description %></td>
    <td><%= video.purchase_price %></td>
    <td><%= video.rental_price %></td>
    <td><%= video.sale_price %></td>
    <td><%= video.image_url %></td>
    <td><%= video.genre %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', video %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_video_path(video) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', video, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Video', new_video_path %>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or 4? Did you include any `attr_accessible`  in your models?

Comment: can you show your `controller` and `model` for `Video`?

Comment: please show two places: heap of `Video` model, and the place in where the error has risen.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "heap of Video" model and the place where the error has risen. I included the video model above, and the error is generated when I navigate to 127.0.0.1/videos and enter the data for the video and click on create. If this is not helpful, please explain further and thank so far for your help.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers, the issue is that you are passing a `params` when you are creating a new `video` that is not in your `attr_accessible`. This is raising the `MassAssignment`. Without seeing what you are passing, it is harder to tell what the problem is. You should include your `new` form and your `create` action from `video_controller`

Comment: @FrancisRodgers, I should have been a bit more clear. By the `new` form, I meant the `_form` partial. `render 'form'` is not helpful to us.

Comment: @FrancisRodgers, you'll need to read some more `ruby` and `rails` tutorials, I think.  You're using CamelCase for your model columns, which is not valid ruby (among others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `_form`, you are including a field for `genre`, which is not an `attr_accessible` in your model. You should change it to `genre_id`.

The best way to represent that is with a `select` option with the labels showing the `Genre_title` and the value is the `genre_id`:

```
<%= f.select :genre_id, Genre.all.map{ |g| [g.genre_title, g.id] } %>
```

Comment: Ideally I would like the Genre_title to be shown in a drop down list box when creating / updating. And just a regular label when displaying. This would prevent users from entering invalid data. As explained in the question...The database doesn't seem to have relationships set up properly. So I could enter a genre in video that doesn't exist in the genre table. Not ideal and is quite a basic thing to overlook in my opinion.

Comment: What I suggested should fix that.

Comment: That worked thank you...Happy christmas and new year.